# CloudBees Back-up Plugin failing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

Below is the error message I'm receiving.  The master is running on OpenSUSE and my Jenkins version is "Jenkins ver. 1.466.12.1 (Jenkins Enterprise by CloudBees 12.11)".

I've verified that I can create a file on the linux box in /mnt/jenkinsbackup.  Is this a user permission problem?

Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jenkins Backup/workspace
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/jenkinsbackup/backup-Jenkins Backup-19.tar.gz (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at com.infradna.hudson.plugins.backup.store.LocalFileStore$1._backup(LocalFileStore.java:50)
    at com.infradna.hudson.plugins.backup.store.BackupFile.backup(BackupFile.java:25)
    at com.infradna.hudson.plugins.backup.BackupBuilder.perform(BackupBuilder.java:95)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:178)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:139)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:480)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1438)
    at hudson.model.Build.run(Build.java:110)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
Build step 'Take backup' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am running jenkins as a daemon and not as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission problem stemmed from the mounted network folder.  Only root had permission to write to it.  One suggestion I found on the internet was to change the ownership of the folder to jenkins:nogroup (since that is what the Jenkins master is running as), but you can't do that to a mounted folder.

But that led me to changing the permissions when mounting the folder in the first place.  I learned I could do this:

mount -t cifs //network_folder_path/jenkins /mnt/jenkins -o username=USERNAME,password=XXXX,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777

That mounted the folder with write permissions for everyone and the job was able to run.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace does say permission error - so perhaps the jenkins app is running as a different user to the one you verified can read and write to that directory?